# Android Bottom Navigation Menu with 4 items

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get 4 items on my bottom menu, but the 4th one isn't animating, should I switch to an entirely different menu format, I thought that this menu type would support 3-5 items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@mipmap/news_icon"
    android:title="@string/title_news" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_schedule" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_team" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_team" />

</menu>
```

Main Activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tibblist.attkapp.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a dumb mistake turns out I wasn't returning true for that switch statement in my onNavigationItemSelected function.